# A Sunny, Funny Rebus

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, knowledge, rebus

Taken together, the meaning of the images below lead to a message.  What is it?

1.
[image: It's a mouth, with a tree inside?]
2.
[image: Uhhhh...]

Note:  The author is not liable for headaches that arrive when trying to interpret this puzzle literally.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's give it a try

> I'm forced to eat broccoli (i feel you, they taste terrible)

First pic :

> a tree in a mouth, *broccoli* resemble tiny trees

Second pic :

> An eye (I); Air Force - Air = Force; This could be interpreteted as "I'm forced"

Not sure though

Edit:

> I originally posted *cauliflowers*, user Jasen suggested *Broccoli*

Comment: @Jasen Are called that in eng too? i didn't know that, i'll edit right away, thank you

Comment: yes, cauliflower is the white vairety. equally bad flavour

Comment: This would be the answer if this were a normal rebus. Unfortunately, I love veggies. I am concerned that I made this puzzle unclear, so I added a tag.

Answer (score 1):

The first 1 could be

> Tree-eat which sounds like treat?

Answer (score 1):

Stepping on the shoulders of QuantumTwinkie and Midori:
The first part could be:

> tree + eat > treat > **tread**

the second part:

> sight(airforce-air) > sight force - sounds like **side force** (also called cornering force [see this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornering_force) - My eyes caught the word `lateral` in this article which is coincidentally in the lateral-thinking tag you added - but probably just a coincidence)

together:

> both parts are connected with tyres and the design of the **tread pattern** is essential for influencing the **side force** of a tyre. Therefore the message might be something like "Make sure you to control the tread pattern on your tyres in order not to slip with your car" :D